# Synonym request for [circe]

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

I recently stumbled upon the [circe-json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circe-json) tag.

It has no description and had 3 questions. The [circe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circe) tag's description states:

> Circe is a JSON library for Scala (and Scala.js).

So this tag ([circe-json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circe-json)) doesn't really add any valuable information that isn't already covered by tagging [scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala), and [circe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circe), and possibly [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json). It would actually make more sense if it were [scala-circe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala-circe) to match similar tags' format, but that's not the point.

I have already removed this tag from those 3 questions but thought that [circe-json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circe-json), and possibly [scala-circe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala-circe), could be a synonym to [circe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circe) to avoid it being mistakenly created again. As I know nothing about scala or circe, I can't suggest the synonym, so I'm bringing it up here.

Comment: Neither of those tags exist. Is it possible to make nonexistent tags synonymous with existing tags? And if you *know nothing about scala or circe*, why does the possibility that it be created again even bother you?

Comment: @oguzismail I am not sure what you mean by *Neither* - only `scala-circe` doesn't exist. To your second question, it adds no value. If it was created once, it can happen again. Simply bringing it up to avoid that... Don't know why that bothers *you*...

Comment: You have already cleaned up the `circe-json` tag, it will be burninated very soon as there are no questions with that tag, practically it doesn't exist anymore. What bothers me is that *doesn't add any value* freaks may cause more harm than good by deleting tags about which they don't know anything.

Comment: @oguzismail I agree with you in general. In this specific case, do you see any added value of having a `circe-json` when the description of `circe` is *Circe is a JSON library for Scala*?

Comment: No, I don't. But that doesn't matter because I don't know anything about scala or circe either. If I were you, I'd let those who do act upon it, that's what I'm saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to perform any action here.

Had you left the [circe-json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circe-json) tag alone, it could have been easily merged into [circe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circe) and a synonym mapping between them created. Since you manually removed it, there's no need to take any additional action. The orphaned [circe-json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circe-json) tag has already been (or will shortly be) removed from the system (since there are no questions remaining with that tag).

We could consider adding a prefix (e.g., [scala-circe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala-circe)) *if* there were naming collisions, but I don't see any. The library name "Circe" is refreshingly unique and does not conflict with any other tags. Absent any name collisions that make disambiguation necessary, we prefer for the tag name to be the name of the product/library/tool.

Comment: I completely agree with your last point (concerning `scala-circe`). But, as I said in a comment, as `circe-json` was created once, it could happen again. Isn't it possible (and justified) to still make it a synonym even though I removed it? And to learn for the future, should I have not removed it to begin with?